# Trying to run a Program called worldforge but it comes up with an error

Tags: 16.04, shared-library, rtmp

I recently downloaded a program called Worldforge, it is a game maker which is open source. I downloaded its executable file and gave it the permissions to run but when i went to start it it came back with this error:

```
/tmp/.mount_dskVs4/usr/bin/ember.bin: error while loading shared libraries: librtmp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried searching for an answer but the only one I found which was relevant did not work, I would be greatful if anyone could help in any way.

Comment: Which version of the client application are you using? Just to rule out potential different behaviour during my tests and yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not trivial to get the `librtmp0` package in Xenial, so my first idea is to use `librtmp.so.1` from the `librtmp1` package instead since there's a good chance that the library is backwards-compatible.

To achieve that we need to create a symbolic link to it in a location where the program executable can find it. Since this is kind of a hack, it would be preferable if other applications don't find the same link automatically. Helpfully, this application adds `~/.ember/lib` to its library search path by default.

I suggest that you

1. assure that the `librtmp1` package is installed,

   ```
   sudo apt install librtmp1
   ```
2. create the directory `~/.ember/lib`,

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.ember/lib
   ```
3. put the symbolic link there.

   ```
   ln -sT /usr/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 ~/.ember/lib/librtmp.so.0
   ```

If the application now fails with a "missing symbol" error message (or something like that) please update your question with the error message and notify me with a comment so I can address it.

---

If there are more missing shared libraries you can [search for their packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents) and

- install them if they're available in Xenial or
- search for newer version of the same shared library (without the version number at the end of the package name) repeat the above process for it.

Comment: I have followed your instructions yet the same error still comes up I'm not sure whether WorldForge added ~/.ember/lib to it's  search path or not.

Comment: What's the output of `readlink -e ~/.ember/lib/librtmp.so.0`?

Comment: It came back with /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1

Comment: Hmm… Could you try to add the library search path explicitly like so: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.ember/lib ./ember-0.7.2.1-x86_64`.

Comment: It have run the command and it came back with bash: ./ember-0.7.2.1-x86_64: No such file or directory            As for what version of the application I am using, i'm currently running version 0.7.2.1

Comment: That was just an example to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable for a single command. I meant for you to you replace the name of the executable with whatever you have. It's the name of file how I downloaded it.